# How to decode the logonHours attribute in Java

Tags: java, active-directory

I am trying to decode the logonHours attribute from Active Directory so that it displays in my Java application properly.  When I look in the attribute editor, it looks like this:

```
logonHours 03 00 00 00 F0 FF 1F F0 FF 1F F0 FF 1F F0 FF 1F F0 FF 1F 00 FF
```

This is precisely 21 bytes long, which is what I expect (each day is encoded in 3 bytes, for a total of 24 bits per day).  This is meant to match the display under logonHours I have.  However, my encoding is as follows (bit-strings for each day)

```
Sun:     00000000 (00) 00000000 (00) 00000000 (00)
Mon-Fri: 00001111 (0F) 11111111 (FF) 11111000 (F8)
Sat:     00000000 (00) 11111111 (FF) 11000000 (C0)
```

This makes me think that there is some encoding happening between the logonHours attribute and the display.  I've looked at the Perl code and the VBScript - converting either of these in Java does a straight conversion, which does not match up with reality.

Does anyone has Java, C#.NET or other pseudo-code for decoding the logonHours attribute properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hate it when I figure these things out ten minutes later after I've thrown up my hands and asked for help.  The key is in this page: [Active Directory Permitted Logon Times with C# .Net 3.5 using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://anlai.wordpress.com/2010/09/07/active-directory-permitted-logon-times-with-c-net-3-5-using-system-directoryservices-accountmanagement/) - specifically, the ordering of the bits and the fact that the array starts with an off-by-1 issue.  Here is the code for Java I came up with:

```
private String[] decodeLogonHours(Attribute attr)
{
    byte[] raw = attr.getValueByteArray();
    String[] days = new String[] { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };
    ArrayList<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int day = 0 ; day < days.length ; day++) {
        byte[] vBits;
        if (day == 6) {
            vBits = new byte[] { raw[19], raw[20], raw[0] };
        } else {
            vBits = new byte[] { raw[day*3+1], raw[day*3+2], raw[day*3+3] };
        }

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append(String.format("%s:", days[day]));
        for (int b = 0 ; b < 3 ; b++) {
            sb.append(" ");
            sb.append(decodeLogonBits(vBits[b]));
        }
        ret.add(sb.toString());
    }

    String[] r = new String[ret.size()];
    ret.toArray(r);
    return r;
}

private String decodeLogonBits(byte b) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append((b & 0x01) > 0 ? "1" : "0");
    sb.append((b & 0x02) > 0 ? "1" : "0");
    sb.append((b & 0x04) > 0 ? "1" : "0");
    sb.append((b & 0x08) > 0 ? "1" : "0");
    sb.append((b & 0x10) > 0 ? "1" : "0");
    sb.append((b & 0x20) > 0 ? "1" : "0");
    sb.append((b & 0x40) > 0 ? "1" : "0");
    sb.append((b & 0x80) > 0 ? "1" : "0");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: The method getValueByteArray(); mentioned here doesn't exist. Could someone suggest an alternative, please?

Comment: This might assist: https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=11860 - basically, they deprecated the method - you can use get() to get the value as an object, then convert to a byte array manually.